# Rails 3 server requirements

Tags: web-server, web-hosting, ruby-on-rails

I am planning to release a rails 3 app to the world. I want to start with a cheap hosting package.

I wonder if these specs are OK to start. I did not find any benchmarks what rails 3 needs.

I planning to rent a vserver
with 1 cpu

guarantied 512 MB Ram max 2GB

Raid 1 25GB HD

root access
available OS:
openSuse 11.1
Debian 5
Ubuntu 8.04 LTS
CentOS 5

I do know it also depends on the app and the number of users accessing the system. But given a general crud application for extended development ... (private beta).

I mean is this enough to start hosting rails3 on linux? And with which distro would you go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VPS you've chosen should be enough for beginning, Nginx+Mongrel+MySQL. The max. 2GB RAM depends on the type of virtualisation your server is on, if you want to play safe you should count with just 512MB. (I mean maybe it's swap...)

I would go with Debian, but if you're not familiar with Linux and servers you should do some "dry practice" first OR take a RoR hosting package: http://www.hostingrails.com

For Mongrel: I don't know if this is currently a problem, but maybe you should also check this: http://jan.varwig.org/archive/rails-3-and-mongrel

Comment: thanks for the comment... I glad that from performance perspective I can run my app on that VPS... but still struggling if I go hosted or not. But it would be a good way to get some experience with managing the whole application even infrastructur...

Answer (score 1):

I would consider going with a rails based host such as Heroku http://heroku.com

The problem with a VPS is you have to manage the software stack i.e. ruby, rails, apache, passenger, mysql. Along with watching out for hackers etc.

Heroku is basically free until you reach about 5gb of server space but that should be plenty to get you through into a beta test.

Comment: I considered this for a start but want to get some experience with the whole stack that's why I am still thinking about driven my tests on my own server. But you are right I can focus more on the application if I have the admin stuff out of the way... but the heroku plans get spicy once this thing grows (but first of all it has to grow =)...)

Answer (score 0):

Those specs sound fine to get you started.  As you said, it'll depend on server load, requests per second, whether or not you have background workers, how much data is in your data store, whether or not you're using Sphinx, etc.  But that's certainly enough horsepower to get going.